# How to check for a Null value in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I have this:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(editTransactionRow.pay_id.ToString()) = False Then
    stTransactionPaymentID = editTransactionRow.pay_id 'Check for null value
End If
```

Now, when `editTransactionRow.pay_id` is Null Visual Basic throws an exception. Is there something wrong with this code?

Comment: What is the type of editTransactionRow?

Comment: You need to post the EXACT error message you are getting if you want help.

Comment: What is this "Null" value? `Nothing`? `DbNull.Value`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using a strongly-typed dataset then you should do this:

```
If Not ediTransactionRow.Ispay_id1Null Then
    'Do processing here
End If
```

You are getting the error because a strongly-typed data set retrieves the underlying value and exposes the conversion through the property. For instance, here is essentially what is happening:

```
Public Property pay_Id1 Then
   Get
     return DirectCast(me.GetValue("pay_Id1", short)
   End Get
   'Abbreviated for clarity
End Property
```

The GetValue method is returning DBNull which cannot be converted to a short.

Comment: Are you sure that syntax above works? what is ediTransactionRow.Ispay_id1Null?

Comment: Why `If Not ediTransactionRow.Ispay_id1Null Then`? The variable is `editTransactionRow.pay_id`. Do you mean `If Not ediTransactionRow.pay_id Is Null Then`?

Answer (score 44):

The equivalent of `null` in VB is `Nothing` so your check wants to be:

```
If editTransactionRow.pay_id IsNot Nothing Then
    stTransactionPaymentID = editTransactionRow.pay_id
End If
```

Or possibly, if you are actually wanting to check for a SQL null value:

```
If editTransactionRow.pay_id <> DbNull.Value Then
    ...
End If
```

Answer (score 11):

editTransactionRow.pay_id is Null so in fact you are doing: null.ToString() and it cannot be executed. You need to check editTransactionRow.pay_id and not editTransactionRow.pay_id.ToString();

You code should be (IF pay_id is a string):

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(editTransactionRow.pay_id) = False Then
    stTransactionPaymentID = editTransactionRow.pay_id 'Check for null value
End If
```

If pay_id is an Integer than you can just check if it's null normally without String...
Edit to show you if it's not a String:

```
If editTransactionRow.pay_id IsNot Nothing Then
    stTransactionPaymentID = editTransactionRow.pay_id 'Check for null value
End If
```

If it's from a database you can use IsDBNull but if not, do not use it.

Comment: Well, I can't check this:
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(editTransactionRow.pay_id1) = False Then
            stTransactionPaymentID = editTransactionRow.pay_id1 'Check for null value
        End If

Comment: read what I have wrote. You can compare your INT if it's false WITHOUT using string...

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the IsDBNull function:

```
If Not IsDBNull(editTransactionRow.pay_id) Then
...
```

Answer (score 6):

```
If Not IsDBNull(dr(0)) Then
    use dr(0)
End If
```

Don't use `= Nothing` or `Is Nothing`, because it fails to check if the datarow value is null or not. I tried, and I make sure the above code worked.

Answer (score 4):

I find the safest way is

```
If Not editTransactionRow.pay_id Is Nothing
```

It might read terribly, but the ISIL is actually very different from IsNot Nothing, and it doesn't try and evaluate the expression, which could give a null reference exception.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check to ensure editTransactionRow is not null and pay_id is not null.

Answer (score 1):

This is the exact answer. Try this code:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(editTransactionRow.pay_id.ToString()) = False Then
    stTransactionPaymentID = editTransactionRow.pay_id 'Check for null value
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If Not editTransactionRow.pay_id AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(editTransactionRow.pay_id.ToString()) = False Then
    stTransactionPaymentID = editTransactionRow.pay_id 'Check for null value
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 If Short.TryParse(editTransactionRow.pay_id, New Short) Then editTransactionRow.pay_id.ToString()
```