# Check if Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken is nothing

Tags: json, vb.net, types, null

According to the Debugger, I've got a variable called `myCancelled` of type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Jtoken with a value of Nothing. I also casted it to Object and all of these conditions fail. My question is simply: How do I check if it's Nothing/Null/False/Empty?

Here's what I've tried. None of these conditions evaluate to true:

```
            If myCancelled Is Nothing Then
                'Doesn't come here
            End If
            If myCancelled = DBNull.Value.ToString Then
                'Doesn't come here
            End If
            If myCancelled = "null" Then
                'Doesn't come here
            End If
            If IsDBNull(myCancelled) Then
                'Doesn't come here
            End If
            If myCancelled Is DBNull.Value Then
                'Doesn't come here
            End If
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(myCancelled) = True Then
                'Doesn't come here
            End If
            If myCancelled.ToString = "Nothing" Then
                'Runtime error
            End If
            If myCancelled = DBNull.Value Then
                'Runtime error
            End If
            If IsNothing(myCancelled) Then
                'Doesn't come here
            End If
```

I'm new to VB.net so any pointers are appreciated.

EDIT

This one worked, but it lets False-positives through (when myCancelled has it value, the conditional is true)

```
            If Not myCancelled Then
                ' It comes here
            End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked. VB is hard to learn when you get used to Java, C#, etc.

```
If Not myCancelled.Equals("Y") Then
    ' It finally came here
End If
```

Comment: Any idea why "Y" was the correct equal check when Nothing is the actual value?

Comment: Perhaps the Equals() method handles Nothings the way I wanted. In hindsight, this may have been a better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378225/how-to-check-for-null-value-in-vb-net