# Why can't I do comparison in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, comparison

```
If (cmbBloodgroup.SelectedItem == null) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a blood group.")
Endif
```

The error 'Expression expected' is on the second equal sign. When I clicked the 'Show potential fixes', it gave me 2 options:
remove unnecessary parentheses, and invert if. The first option doesn't remove the error. The second option makes it like this:

```
cmbBloodgroup.SelectedItem =IsNot null
```

But I want the condition for it to be null. Idk what I should change here. (I'm checking combobox. If it's empty, I want to show a messagebox)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check for a Null value in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378225/how-to-check-for-a-null-value-in-vb-net)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. I'm checking combobox, not string. I tried using the .IsNullorEmpty but it gave an exception 'Object variable or With block variable not set'

Comment: If you want to write code in VB then you need to learn how to write code in VB first. Don't try to write code and expect us to fix the mess without first putting in the time and effort to learn the basics. There are loads of beginner tutorials around that would have shown you how to do that.

Comment: Yes [it does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378263/11683), @Newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vb syntax is as below , what you had tried is c#

```
  if cmbBloodgroup.SelectedItem is Nothing Then
       MessageBox.Show("Please select a blood group.")
    End if
```

Answer (score -1):

```cs
cmbBloodgroup.SelectedItem == null
```

is C# syntax. The VB version of that would be:

```
cmbBloodgroup.SelectedItem Is Nothing
```